# asp.net mvc3 - displaying a list of RadioButtons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I m trying to get a list of radiobuttons from the controller and display it on the View but it dosent seem to be working. I have the following model

```
public class Module
{

    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

}

In the controller I am getting the list of modules and passing it to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SelectAdmin()
    {
        //getting the list of modules from db
        List<Module> modulelst = GetModules(); 
        ViewBag.lstm = modulelst;

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Now in the View I'm trying to display the list of modules in the form of RadioButtons/Checkboxes and getting the corresponding id for the module which is selected.

The code for the View I am trying is as follows:

```
@model List<MyFriday.Domain.Model.Client>
```

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectAdmin", "CMAdmin", null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "UpdateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "EditForm" }))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

```
<fieldset>

<div class="content">                     
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                <div>
                Select the Admin Type:
                 </div>
                <div id="divModules">
                @foreach (var Modules in ViewBag.lstm)
                {
                    <div class="formlabel">
                        <div align="right" class="label" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative;">
                            @(Modules.First().Title)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formelement">
                        <input type="radio" id=""/>
                            @(Modules.First().ModuleId)

                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">
                    </div>
                }
                </div>
                <input id="Submit1"  type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:cancelconfirm(this)"/>   

            }
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>

        </div>

</fieldset>
```

}

The Above View is not getting displayed

Can anyone please suggest me a solution ?

Comment: The View is not getting display at all

Comment: Looks like the error is in the view, you can use Fiddler2 to see what the error message is and post it here which will be useful.

Comment: @Darren Davies : Fiddler2 dosent debug .cshtml page I guess ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would change the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SelectAdmin()
{
    //getting the list of modules from db
    List<Module> modulelst = GetModules(); 
    // ViewBag.lstm = modulelst;

    return PartialView(modulelst);
}
```

Then change the View... add the decalration it uses the model on the first line:

```
@model List<Module>
```

and then change the for loop to:

```
            @foreach (var module in Model)
            {
                <div class="formlabel">
                    <div align="right" class="label" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => module.Title, true)

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="formelement">
                    <input type="radio" id=""/>
                        @RadioButtonFor(modelItem => module.ModuleId, new { @id="ModuleId"})

                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: there was an error with the model. Its solved. Thanks for the answer ! It helped me.